# Error in Android Studio cache.properties

Tags: android, caching

Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Petrusic\AndroidStudioProjects\askramarnovi.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

> C:\Users\Petrusic\AndroidStudioProjects\askramarnovi.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: See @user3484700 answer in this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified. It solves this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've already tried simply to delete **gradle folder**. then restarted Android Studio and the problem solved

Answer (score 5):

Look for a cache.properties.lock file, delete it and rebuild project

Answer (score 3):

> cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

To fix this problem go to :

```
 C:\Users\[Usuario]\.gradle\caches\
```

Delete folders `\2.4` and `\2.8`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Restart `Android Studio` y Sync project with Gradle Files!.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably something wrong with your cached dependencies:

Try to rebuild your project:

```
gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

There is very easy solution for this problem 
just goto File in the menu bar and say Invalidate Cache and Restart 
it will be all right..

I hope this might solve your problem because it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete yourproject/.gradle directory
2. goto File in the menu bar and say Invalidate Cache and Restart it will be all right..

Answer (score 0):

First copy the scripts folder (Which is shown in the studio) `C:\Users\[User name]\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts` to some other place

then Delete all cache.properties.lock files from your `C:\Users\[User name]\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts` (Which file is shown in studio)

For every deletion Rebuild Project (`Build -> Rebuild Project`) if the studio showing the error in other properties.lock file means delete those all and rebuild project

After this you may get error like `No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'`

then include

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

and synch (This option is at top of the build.graddle)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just goto file > invalidiate caches/restart > pop-up will open then click on "invalidiate and restart" button

Answer (score 0):

If you receive error related to cache just check & make sure you have put **org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false**