# Cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started using Android Studio 1.3 sdk 24 and it has worked fine until today. I get this error message about cache.properties and I delete that cache file but now I am getting this error message:

> Error:C:\Users\user1.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\asLocalRepo15_dhjxrnvsgiyg1ow3dfj4myl7\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

I try file/invalidate caches/restart.. and rebuild project but am still getting this error message. How do I fix it?

Comment: Check if disabling **Instant Run** in the *Preferences* of *Android Studio* makes a difference. In was the solution for the issue in my setup.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You don't have to delete all `.gradle` folders and no need to reinstall Android Studio.

I have the latest version of Android Studio and I faced that problem, the only thing that worked for me is to:

1. Navigate to `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.x\`
2. Copy the folder **scripts** , **scripts-remapped** and paste it somewhere safe just in case anything went wrong you will place it back
3. Delete this folder **scripts** and **scripts-remapped**  from the directory `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.x\`
4. Sync Project with Gradle Files and you are done.

[image]

When you sync your project Android Studio will generate new cache files.

You also need to delete buildOutputCleanup.lock from projectLocation/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup in case the above 4 steps do not work out.

It worked for me I hope it will work for you.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No need of reinstall anything. Thanks.

Comment: same problem as mine, but \caches\2.2.1\
worked for me, thanks

Comment: Thanks alot, after removing script-remapped, it worked for me too

Comment: Why do you hide your username?

Comment: replace username with the name of your current user at your computer to have a correct path.

Comment: Shookran, it's arabic for Thank you :)

Comment: I'm from Lebanon my native Language is Arabic and tekram:p

Comment: TWO deletions were required for me.  `.gradle\caches\...` as well as `(project location)\.gradle\2.1.4.1`

Comment: after restore my pc this problem occured. but it works for me now perfectly. no needs to apply 2nd step.

Comment: It really works for me by removing the scripts and scripts-remapped from  gradle caches

Comment: perfect answer, i just removed those 2 folder and reload project and it worked

Comment: for me: in the <projectLocation>/.gradle folder it was the "cache.properties.lock" file that I had to delete

Answer (score 11):

#### Reinstall Android Studio again is not an option!

To fix the problem:

> cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

go to :

```
 C:\Users\[User]\.gradle\caches\
```

Delete folders `\2.4` and `\2.8`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Restart `Android Studio`!.

Comment: If deleting `2.4` and `2.8` doesn't work for you, make sure you take note of the folder number in the error message. It might be something else other than `2.4` or `2.8`. Mine was `2.14.1`

Answer (score 8):

***You don't have to reinstall Android Studio*** or no need to delete all .gradle folder.

I am reinstalled the latest version of Android Studio and still I faced that problem. It caused my to rename the "Android Projects" folder on my desktop in my case.

The only thing that you have to do:

> **1-Navigate to C:\Users\user_name.gradle\caches\2.4**  or (2.8 if error in it otherwise)
>
> **2-Copy the folder "2.4" or "2.8" and paste it somewhere safe just in case anything went wrong you will place it back**
>
> **3-Delete this error folder from the directory C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.4\  (or \2.8)**
>
> **4-Close the Android studio & restart it.**

During restart it sync your project & Android Studio will generate new **cache** files.

It worked for me I hope it will work for you... :)

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem, I just delete `.gradle` from `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.4\` and from my application too.

Of course close Android Studio and start Android Studio again.

Comment: Deleting the .gradle directory from the project folder was enough to solve the issue for me

Comment: This worked for me.  The accepted answer, above, did not work for me...  I had already deleted from the `user\.gradle` location.  That was not enough.  I had to delete from your suggested: `(project location)\.gradle`.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my question, but I do not know whether it is the optimal solution:

I deleted all `.gradle` folders in user library and reinstalled android and then it worked.

Comment: Damn and people complain about restarting windows after an update... Then Google came with their products...

Answer (score 4):

**No need to reinstall** anything.

Just delete the `2.4` and `2.8` folder located at `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches`directory and reopen android studio. It will generate new cash files so now the build should be successful.

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution. Go ahead and create an empty `cache.properties` file under the path specified in the error log. The error should then disappear.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the above examples i have tried resolving with extra steps:

1. Navigate to the respective folder C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.14.1\
2. Copy both the folders "scripts" and "scripts-remapped" into a safe place.
3. Now, DELETE BOTH THE FOLDERS "scripts" and "scripts-remapped" in the location      C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.14.1\
4. Finally, try to sync the gradle.
5. Android Studio will ask to Upgrade the Gradle plugin. So click on Upgrade the gradle.

(If not try to Restart the Android Studio IDE completely.)

Finally, it is done for me...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Removing the {project-path}/.gradle/buildOutputCleanupcache.properties.lock

Work for me..

Comment: This solution worked for since I did not have the folder .cache. Somehow it got deleted and none of the solutions above worked.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the "scripts" folder and rebuilding the project will solve this problem.

Comment: @Kaisar Hossein - I hope I've understood what you wanted to say. Please note that the Community prefers posts without expressions like "thanks", "hope this helps" etc. If I misunderstood you can always edit your own posts as often as you like :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why a great developer as Google can't manage this issue by them selves it is very easy to delete the cached folder and regenerate it programmatically.
Any way just navigate to C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\ and open the latest version folder, then delete the scripts folder.
Go to android studio and sync project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder indicated in the error message. Delete the cache.properties.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

I [download](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) gradle and changed path of gradle from C drive to D drive and fixed it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i am using `Android studio 3.0.1`,

Well, Don't Reinstall the Android studio there is no need of reinstalling the Whole software

Do the following step and hope this will solve your problem.....

step - 1. Go to `C:\Users\*user_name_of_your_system*\.gradle\caches\2.x/`

step - 2. Delete this folder `scripts` and `scripts-remapped`

step - 3. Than in your android studio, Go to `Tools/Android/Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Done :)

if still problem is not solved than -

step - 4. Delete both the `Build` folder and than repeat `step- 3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and more accurate approach to this problem is to remove from your project's
 `.gradle/<version>/buildOutputCleanup` folder the file `cache.properties.lock` 
This will do the trick. After that, just rebuild or sync your project.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above,I faced same problem: Try this

1. Remove scripts and scripts-remmaped folders in C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.14.1\
2. restart android studio

THIS WORKED FOR ME.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer doesn't seem to add anything that previous answers haven't already mentioned. StackOverflow is not a forum and as such answers should only be added if they provide new information. For more on how this site works try taking [the tour.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)