# Gradle build not executing because it can't find cache.properties

Tags: android, caching, gradle

My gradle build in android Studio is failing because it can't access the cache.properties file. I have tried invalidating all caches and retrying but that did not work. I also reinstalled all the SDK tools. Here is the error I'm getting

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Siddharth\AndroidStudioProjects\IntentAssignment.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   C:\Users\Siddharth\AndroidStudioProjects\IntentAssignment.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   Blockquote

Any advice on what to do, here is the complete console output:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Siddharth\AndroidStudioProjects\IntentAssignment.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   C:\Users\Siddharth\AndroidStudioProjects\IntentAssignment.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 0.747 secs

Answer (score 4):

delete gradle folder, quit Android Studio and Start again fixed this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

run cmd 
write `%temp%`
then temp folder open delete all file in temp then rebuild your project
hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

After Search i found this answer and worked for me

thanks to @Salam El-Banna and @Naveed Ahmad

You don't have to delete all **.gradle** folders and no need to reinstall Android Studio.

I have the latest version of Android Studio and I faced that problem, the only thing that worked for me is to:

1- Navigate to

> C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.x\

2- Copy the folder **scripts** , **scripts-remapped** and paste it somewhere safe just in case anything went wrong you will place it back

3- Delete this folder **scripts** and **scripts-remapped** from the directory C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.x\

4- Sync Project with Gradle Files and you are done.

[image]

When you sync your project Android Studio will generate new cache files.

It worked for me I hope it will work for you.

reference:
[Cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your Gradle folder
2. Invalidate cache and Restart

Simply these steps fix your issue.