# Gradle project refresh failed error after restoring system files

Tags: android

My system just recovered from an unexpected error and I had to perform system restore, unfortunately am getting this error afterwards:

```
Gradle 'project-name' project refresh failed
   Error:C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts
   \settings_33k2gi7mg22wg4z19a3j54pnd\SettingsScript\buildscript
   \cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I've tried rebuilding the project, cleaning the project, invalidating caches and restarting with no luck.I even tried downgrading gradle to an older version with no luck.Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)