# Android - Build fails with exception

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am building a project for quite a while and my friend recently started working on it as well. We are using github, we integrated it into android studio and everything seemed to be fine. However, after his first push, my build broke.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong: 
failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.>java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.10\classAnalysis\cache.properties (System cannot find the given file)
```

I looked at other StackOverflow threads as well, but none of the fixes worked for me. Any ideas? Tell me what to include, I ll include in comments.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I was able to find a resolution from 
[Cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Use the File manager and navigate to the 2.10 folder, You will then want to copy the classAnalysis folder and paste it somewhere safe (I pasted mine into the folder up from 2.10, the caches folder). Once its in a safe place delete the version of it inside the 2.10 folder. Then go to android studio and click Build>Make Project. It should regenerate that folder. For me after it generated it I had the same error in the jarSnapshots folder. Did the same thing again and it worked out for me.