# Can not find gradle file error in Android Studio when building project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing in Android App , and the error happened like the following log when I building Android project.

It show the system can not find the file.

```
Error:C:\Users\Wun\.gradle\caches\3.3\scripts-remapped\asLocalRepo41_9u1u823ans26s9bc90r7dl40\28vlxmqnnm21es7qn91g496cu\cp_init1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try "invalidate cache and restart" your android studio from File menu

Comment: @satvindersingh I have try , it is the same.

Comment: Check this answer on stack overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413965/8178922

Comment: I guess you are facing the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) ,check it out

Comment: Thanks , the answer of the link is working!