# Project refresh failed, JetGradlePlugin$_apply_closure2$_closure4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Before this error occurs I had another issue and solved it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified#). It solved my problem but after that I am facing  this error i.e **Error:JetGradlePlugin$_apply_closure2$_closure4**
 have anyone faced this issue? If yes it would be very helpful.

*Tried clean and rebuild project but no luck.

Comment: The problem got solved after doing 2-3 times of Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solved the issue. I will be keeping this question here, hope it may helps others in future for the beginners may be.

1. Clean the project from build menu.
2. Than rebuild and do Invalidate Caches / Restarts.

This process solved my issue as of now. I'll let you know if it occurs again.