# Flutter - Android Studio Flamingo Execution Failed

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, aapt2

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4ca28c4a71705f8a687c69dda140a277\transformed\core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Flutter version 3.7.10 and  Dart version 2.19.6

I have installed Windows Universal C Runtime using Visual studio installation community version. But still facing the same issue. If anybody has any other solution to resolve this issue kindly let me know

Comment: check my answer it is working for me in android  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070809/12936324

Comment: Thanks for providing me with a solution. But I found the problem the anti virus is blocking the android studio that is why the execution is failing again and again. I checked in other pcs which does not have anti virus it is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

https://cazimirroman.medium.com/how-to-solve-the-execution-failed-for-aarresourcescompilertransform-issue-in-android-studio-90b7819facaa

Basically it's saying you could run as admin and/or restart the PC.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34247007)

Comment: It’s not a link-only answer, I stated below the link what part about the result might be the solution.