# Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:/.../.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts/cache.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

How can I fix this error? can anyone help me?

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:/.../.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts/cache.properties
>   (No such file or directory)

its my first time to encounter this error in android :3

Comment: Maybe you have wrong path to Gradle?.

Comment: I didn't touch,view,move or replace the Gradle all the time. how is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't this error. Try clean project and build again. If it doesn't help post project file structure and full log.

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:http...:compileLint
:http...:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:http...:checkReleaseManifest
:http...:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:http...:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE

Comment: A similar question here and a provided answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31275847/5374779

Comment: :http...:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../.../Desktop/.../.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts/cache.properties (No such file or directory)
> /.../.../Desktop/.../.gradle/.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts/cache.properties (No such file or directory)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.898 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: @NNS I tried it already but it didnt help sorry

Answer (score 0):

well I found a solution for my own question and it works perfectly fine

in cmd/terminal enter this process

- cd sampleLocation/projectFolder
- cd .gradle
- ls
- cd 2.8
- ls
- cd taskArtifacts/
- ls
- rm cache.properties.lock

->cd sampleLocation/projectFolder
(locate your project)
->cd .gradle
(it will direct you to your Gradle)
->ls
(it will display the version of your Gradle i think then)
->cd 2.8
(2.8 is just my example of my Gradle version that displays earlier in ls then enter "ls" again)
->ls
(it will display the taskArtifacts then go to taskArtifacts)
->cd taskArtifacts/
(it will direct you to your taskArtifacts then enter "ls" again)
->ls
(it will display this "cache.properties.lock   fileHashes.bin          fileSnapshots.bin       outputFileStates.bin askArtifacts.bin" and then enter this "rm cache.properties.lock ")
->rm cache.properties.lock 
(it will remove the cache and it will create a new cache for your project)

Answer (score 0):

The answer here did lead me to the problem, but a more reasonable approach is to delete the `.gradle` in both your `$HOME` directory and the project directory.